# How to solve : [Vue warn]: Error when rendering component on the vue.js 2?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, laravel-5.3, vuejs2, vue-component

My component code (**SearchResultView.vue**) is like this :

```
<template>
    ...
</template>

<script>

    export default{
        props:['search','category','shop'],
        created(){
            ...
        },
        data(){
            return{
                loading:false
            }
        },
        computed:{
            list:function(){
                var a = this.$store.state.product;
                a = JSON.stringify(a)
                a = JSON.parse(a)
                console.log(a.list[12])
                ...
            }
        },
        methods:{
            ...
        }
    }
</script>
```

When I check this : `console.log(a.list[12])` on the console, the result :

[image]

I want display value of name

I try like this :

```
console.log(a.list[12].name)
```

On the console, exist error like this :

> [Vue warn]: Error when rendering component  at C:\xampp\htdocs\chelseashop\resources\assets\js\components\SearchResultView.vue:
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

How can I solve the error?

Comment: Since this is a rendering problem you will need to privde the template you use to us. Most probably you access data before it's loaded or you pass false properties

Comment: What is the response of : `console.log(JSON.stringify(a.list[12]))`?

Comment: @Saurabh, `{"id":12,"name":"Bunga Gandeng","photo":"bunga6.jpg","price":762913,"stock":36,"total_sold":54,"total_view":0,"weight":68,"store_id":1,"shop_name":"Bunga Airi","formatted_address":"Kemang"}`

Comment: As @FrankProvost says, please add your template it seems that here is the problem, also I suppose that at the end of your `list` function you're returning a value, but could you please add whole function's body?

Comment: try assigning `console.log(a.list[12])` to a variable like this: `var z=console.log(a.list[12])` and then use `z.name` and tell me whats the output after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it is a computed, its value probably changes during the life of your program. You should check to ensure that `a.list[12]` exists before trying to get a member from it.

```
if (a.list[12])
    console.log(a.list[12].name);
```